# Properly Punctuating a Parenthetical

Tags: punctuation, syntactic-analysis

I have a line in a document "Create New Path" which I would like to change to "Create New Path or Update Old Path?" including the "?"

In my correspondence with others they may think I'm asking a question with improper grammar. For example, I wrote:

> The new header for that section will be line A, "Create New Path or
>   Update Old Path?".

I think this is incorrect punctuation, but I did it anyway to get my point across. Is there a correct way to punctuate so those reading understand the "?" will be included in the change?

Comment: Reverse the options. Then the small letter following the Question mark emphasises the value of each option **"Update Old Path? or Create New Path."**

Comment: Unfortunately the text must stay as it is.

Comment: If you're asking about ending a sentence with **Path?".** the majority of style guides, I believe, would recommend omitting the period, as being an unnecessary punctuation mark in this situation. The same would be true if you were writing a line of dialogue that read _The man asked, "What time is it?"_

Comment: This isn't a parenthetical

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although there is some leeway in the use of articles in the creation of headers, the correct *punctuation* is just as you've written it:

> "Create a New Path or Update an Old Path?"

Answer (score -1):

I think you want: ... "Create New Path?" or "Update old path?".  If these are  'buttons' then eliminate the '?' in both.